# Java display current time

Tags: java, date, time, timer

I have a code which shows me the current date and time when I run my application

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Now it shows me: 2012/12/11 00:36:53 when I run it.

But I want it to count the time during running it.

So by example now when I run it on 00:37:53 it shows this time, but I want 00:37:53 at starting and I stop running it on 00:40:55 . I want that it shows me 00:37:53, 00:37:54, 00:37:55 and so on.

Now how can I do this?

Comment: so basically you are asking for a countdown timer ??

Comment: I'm confused -- you want a clock to continuously print to stdout while the application runs?

Comment: yes i want a clock who is continuously while running my application so not showing onlyone time but when the time in real will be 1:04:03 this will be in my app also

Comment: Is it web application or desktop application created in swing?

Answer (score 8):

How about using a timer, such as [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)? (Do not make mistake in the import, there are more Timer classes.)

```
public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
    final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    int interval = 1000; // 1000 ms

    new Timer(interval, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            System.out.println(dateFormat.format(now.getTime()));
        }
    }).start();

    Thread.currentThread().join();
}
```

This will simply execute the body of the ActionListener every second, printing the current time.

The `Thread.join` call on the last line is not universally necessary, it's just needed for this example piece of code to run until the process is manually stopped. Otherwise, it would immediately stop.

In a real application, in case it's a Swing app, then the timer should handle threading by itself, so you won't have to worry about it.

---

### Edit

Integrating the above sample into your application is fairly simple, just add it into the `initGUI` method and instead of printing the current time to System.out set change the text of the given label:

```
public void initGUI() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    setLayout(null);

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    tijd = new JLabel(dateFormat.format(now.getTime()));
    tijd.setBounds(100, 100, 125, 125);
    window.add(tijd);

    new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            tijd.setText(dateFormat.format(now.getTime()));
        }
    }).start();

    pack();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not mention the technical platform of your user interface, such as [Swing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)), [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/), [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com), web, or so on. So I'll not address those specifics. The basic approach here applies to all the UI technologies.

Two basic ideas:

- Create an element in your user interface to represent the current moment. Could be a text label or a fancy widget such as an animated clock face.
- Background thread regularly captures the current moment for an update to the display of that UI element. Be careful in how the background thread reaches into the UI thread. Use the appropriate UI technique to communicate the new date-time value and cause the UI widget to update.

### Executor

For Swing, the Swing Timer may be appropriate (not sure of current status of that technology). But otherwise, learn how to use a `ScheduledExecutorService` to have a separate thread repeatedly capture the current moment. Search Stack Overflow to learn much more about that `Executor`.

### java.time

Use the `Instant` class to capture the current moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution up to nanoseconds.

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
```

Pass that object to the UI thread.

On the UI thread, apply the user’s desired/expected time zone `ZoneId` to produce a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZobedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

If you need a String to represent that date-time call `toString` or use `DateTimeFormatter`. Notice the `ofLocalized…` methods on `DateTimeFormatter`.

Search Stack Overflow for many hundreds of related Questions and Answers for more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void ShowTime() {
        new Timer(0, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Date d = new Date();
                SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy hh:mm:ss a");
                time.setText(s.format(d));                 //time= jlabel 
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Continuously Change time(refresh every second)

Answer (score 0):

Use simple date formatter with hh:mm as format.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM a");
```

[Click here for complete program.](http://java-interview-questions.com/how-to-display-time-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a loop with an increment statement, so the clock will keep ticking until  given condition.

Comment: pretty bad idea!, loop is not intend to make that, instead use a Tread.